# load url in browser

Tags: jquery, ajax

can I load the url in the browser ?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click','#see',function(){
        var ID = $("#rowid").val();


        $.ajax({
            type:'GET',
            url:'news.php?var='+ID,
            data:'var='+ID,
            success:function(response){  

            }
        }); 
    });
});
```

Comment: Do you mean the content received from that url in the ajax request? If so yes that is what ajax is used for but  where do you want to put it?

Comment: I need the the  variable ?var= to be in the url when I request it

Comment: Set that in the url string or in `data` but not both

Comment: I didnot understand\

Answer (score 0):

Please clarify, whether you need to redirect to your page (which inside your application) or external url?

In your success method you can use below,

```
//As an HTTP redirect (back button will not work )
window.location.replace("http://www.example.com");

//if you click on a link (it will be saved in the session history)  
window.location.href = "http://www.example.com";
```